# Input button not working in phonegap and ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, phonegap, html-framework-7

i am developing a cross platform app using php mysql as back end . i am calling a ajax request to login user which working fine in browser. but when i test it on phonegap and ionic. the click button not working. app just do nothing when i click on login button.
ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#but_submit").click(function(){
                    var username = $("#txt_uname").val().trim();
                    var password = $("#txt_pwd").val().trim();

                    if( username != "" && password != "" ){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'checkUser.php',
                            type:'post',
                            data:{username:username,password:password},
                            success:function(response){
                                var msg = "";
                                if(response == 1){
                                    window.location = "home.html?username="+username+"";
                                    localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
                                    localStorage.setItem("email", username);
                                }else{
                                    msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                                }
                                $("#message").html(msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

and here is html form

```
<form>                    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txt_uname" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" required />
                    <input type="password" class="textbox" id="txt_pwd" name="txt_pwd" placeholder="Password" required/>
                    <input type="button" style="height:40px; border:#FFFFFF solid thin;" class="btn" value="Submit" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" />
</form>
```

i have tested it on browser and its working fine but on phonegap and ionic its not working. also access of external url from whitelist are allowed . help me to resolve this. thanks

Comment: See: http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/debugging/

Comment: cant find any relevant solution there .@BrahmaDev